# Background position: put left corner in center

Tags: css, background

Hope this image explains more, what I want
[image: bg-pos.png]

(The transparent part of the image should indicate it is bigger than the `.content` Div :-)

Is there an almost save way (preferably just CSS) to let a background image start at the center?

```
background-position: center top;
```

… would use the image's center, not the left corner.

I can't manipulate the image itself (using a transparent offset) nor use absolute values.

Comment: for that you need to add "background-size:cover"

Comment: That's exactly the opposite of what the asker wants.

Comment: You'd have to set the `background-position` a pixel value (in X axis). With keyword or percentage value, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Please provide the code you are currently working with. As far as I am aware there isn't a way to achieve this using `background` properties alone, you may be able to fake the effect you are after by using pseudo elements.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this with a background image on the desired element without using absolute values. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648245/how-does-css-computation-for-background-percentages-work/25649073#25649073) for an illustration of why. In a nutshell, background positioning with percentages and keyword values works much like a sliding puzzle, keeping the image strictly within the element's background positioning area. Only absolute values are exempt from this behavior.

You could cheat by making the image a background of a pseudo-element of the desired element instead, but this requires the desired element to be relatively positioned and act as a containing block for all absolutely positioned descendants, including the pseudo-element:

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.content#one { width: 100px; }
.content#two { width: 200px; }

.content::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/150x150) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="one"></div>
<div class="content" id="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with pseudo elements

```css
.cimg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.cimg::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url("http://www.youramazingplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/sunset-5.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cimg">

</div>
```