# CSS background-image transitions effects not working as expected

Tags: css, cross-browser

Ok, so I'm working on this swipe effect on hover using div and background image. background image uses outer div max-width and inner div with padding-bottom percentage to maintain aspect ratio.

There are a few things here I don't understand.

1. I was very surprised that my %200 background position only pushed the image over a few pixels, in the end, a massive 7100% was required to fully move the image over so the repeated image was fully visible.
2. When I set the padding-bottom to anything over 54%, the transition and everything stops working.
3. This '7100%' seems to produce the right effect in chrome, firefox, and opera, but not safari.

My fiddle, thoughts?
https://jsfiddle.net/riegersn/a3mnr9um

```
.container {
      max-width: 480px;
    }


.project {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: contain;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  padding-bottom: 54%;
  &:hover {
    background-position: 7100% 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I have a suspicion that the values for `background-position` and `background-repeat` are why you need to use _unexpected_ values. I'm guessing you're using those values so you don't have to customize the images in some way?

Comment: Well yes, I hadn't considered simply modifying the image. But what do you say to issue #2?

Comment: I'd say it's related to my first comment. Sorry I don't have specifics for you but if you remove those properties or mix them then some sort of transition does happen (all be it not what you want). If you doubled up your image you could show half of it and then transition to the other half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to using percent with position background images, it gets somewhat complicated.

> Moving a background image by X% means it will align the X% point in
> the image to the X% point in the container. For example, 50% means it
> will align the middle of the image with the middle of the container.
> 100% means it will align the last pixel of the image with the last
> pixel of the container, and so on.
>
> ---
>
> Src: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/)

---

Here is also a very good explanation of how it works: [how-does-css-computation-for-background-percentages-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648245/how-does-css-computation-for-background-percentages-work)

---

May I recommend a pseudo element instead, where you can use `transform`, which performs better than `background-position` when it comes to animations.

With a pseudo you can also zoom, rotate, skew, animate back and forth, etc., stuff which is simply not possible with the background-image alone.

What happens in below sample is, I made the pseudo twice the width of the `project`, positioned it half its width to the left (`left: -100%`, where 100% comes from its parent) and then, when hovered, I move it back so left becomes 0 (`transform: translateX(50%)`), where `translateX(50%)` means move it half its own width to the right.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 480px;
}

.project {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 54%;
  background-size: 0;
}
.project::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%; top: 0;
  width: 200%; height: 100%;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: inherit;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
.project:hover::before {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="project" style="background-image:url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/fpha4d0uyu71whe/pandora_thumb.png?dl=1')">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is much better, it also resolves issue 2. Can you explain a bit why using pseudo here works and why? I'm not completely following the left and width properties being set to what they are.

Comment: @ShawnRieger I made the pseudo twice the width of the `project`, positioned it half its width to the left (`left: -100%`, where 100% comes from its parent) and then, when hovered, I move it back so left becomes 0 (`transform: translateX(50%)`), where `translateX(50%)` means move it half its own width to the right. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does! Excellent! Had to wrap my head around it for a minute! Thanks!

Comment: @ShawnRieger Very good...updated my answer with that comment

Answer (score 2):

### The setup

I've modified your fiddle for demonstration purposes. The image proportions and relevant CSS properties are the same. So let's first have a look at what we *get* from our setup:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 480px;
  background: orange;
}

.project {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wurh4.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-bottom: 54%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="project">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
Image width:      504px
Image height:     276px
Container width:  480px
Container height: 259.2px // FireFox 53
```

Because of `background-size: contain` our background-image has the following dimensions:

```
BG image height:  259.2px
BG image width:   473.3217...px
```

The height is equal to the container height (this is simply how [`contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size?v=example#Values) works in this scenario). The width is then calculated as follows: `(259.2 / 276) * 504`.

```
Difference D:     480px - 473.3217...px = 6.6782...px
```

This is the gap you can discover in the above snippet. Because of the `background-position-x: center` you see ~3px on the left and another ~3px gap on the right.

---

### How background-position and percentages work

In short: a `background-position-x: 50%` centers the center of the background-image to the center of the container. So a `background-position-x: 100%` will simply align the the right side of the image to the right side of the container.

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  background: orange;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wurh4.png");
  background-position: 90% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

The above calculated difference D is exactly what the `100%` in `background-position-x: 100%` would be represented in px.

---

### 7100% is not random

```
Difference D:     6.6782...px
Factor F:         480px / D = 71.8749...
```

To move our background-image completely out of the viewing range we would have to set `background-position-x: 7174%`. Questions 1 should now be answered. If you skipped everything up to here, the short answer is: a value of `100%` has a very special meaning when it comes to the `background-position` property.

> When I set the padding-bottom to anything over 54%, the transition and everything stops working.

Yes, because then the width of the background-image gets bigger than the width of the container.

Comment: No, I did not skip to the end! This is a great help in understanding my original issues. Thank you for taking the time to do this.

Comment: Ah, I'm glad that it helped you! I was a little bit in a hurry at the end but together with the proposed solution by LGSon this should be sufficient.